# How to make any sklearn model verbose?

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, sklearn-pandas, dbscan

I am trying to implement a data clustering algorithm, specifically DBSCAN, using Scikit learn. I am using the Jaccard Index for my metric. However, `DBSCAN()` doesn't have the `verbose` parameter that other models have. This means I can't see which epoch my DBSCAN is on and I have no intuition of how long it is going to take. Also, to my (somewhat limited) knowledge of clustering algorithms, they may fail to ever converge if they get stuck in a loop; hence, knowing which iteration the algorithm is in is quite important.

Is there any way that I can have scikit print info on which epoch I am on? If not, is there a way to code such a function myself and have scikit learn run this function at the end of every output (or something like that)? Or do I have to code the entire `DBSCAN()` function myself to have printed statements about the epoch and the associated accuracy scores?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with an option to let Scikit's implementation of `DBSCAN()` print the iteration it is in. Nevertheless, you could try to reason about your data whether it would make sense that it takes so long to converge.

`DBSCAN()` works really well if you have regions with dense clusters (in any shape; which is one of its main advantages) and other regions with few datapoints. So, if you first try to visualize your data in 2D or 3D after PCA, you could obtain a first indication of whether your data is one blob or whether there are high and low density regions. If the data is indeed a blob, then the `DBSCAN()` likely will have a hard time converging and if it converges it would like choose one cluster with many anomalies. Moreover, your epsilon parameter is a very important one in `DBSCAN()` because that will actually determine the proximity of points that will be regarded to one cluster. The lower the epsilon, the more clusters you likely find/

I think the above points might explain why your clustering algorithm takes so long to run, because the `DBSCAN()` normally has a roughly linear (to the number of datapoints) computational complexity.

Comment: My dataset has 6,500 columns and 60,000 rows. Maybe that is too big for `DBSCAN()` to run in a period of time that is not absurd (15+ hours). I have considered PCA but my data is binary (ie. all datapoints are either a 0 or 1) and I have read online that PCA is not great for binary data. Do you maybe know an alternative to PCA that is not too difficult to implement? I have seen some online that would require me to code the whole thing but are too complex mathematically to understand.

Comment: I see... I am not too familiar with working only with binary features, but what you maybe can do is perform a PCA/MDS on a similarity matrix and then just use this as an exploratory tool to check whether you could identify some partitions by face-value? Nonetheless, I do think that the dimensions of your dataset are causing much of run-time problems. Maybe, extensive pre-processing (collinearity removal) will help speed up the DBSCAN() quite a bit?